# How to add a python package dependance to a debian package?

Tags: debian, dpkg, packaging, deb

I have a `debian` package whose content requires that a certain python package is installed with `pip installed <python-package>`.

**How should I precisely configure my `.deb` package (probably through `debian/rules`) in order for `<python-package>` to be installed with the package (i.e when launching `dpkg -i mypackage.deb`)?**

Comment: see here https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control

Comment: IMO this scenario contradicts a purpose of package management. The purpose of sane package management is that while installing a package, you install only the packages which were built on a repository maintained by package maintainers. During a package installation or a build, the package "rules" should not install anything from "unknown" sources or to download some random stuff from internet.

Comment: Packaging that dependency would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is not trivial to do. There are multiple possibilities outlined in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327543/how-can-a-debian-package-install-python-modules-from-pypi) and its answers, but as @FerencWagner said, the best and most correct solution is to re-package all dependencies as debian packages.

Some python packages are already available as debian packages, like jsonpickle:

```
$ apt-cache search jsonpickle
python-jsonpickle - Python library for serializing object graphs into JSON (Python 2)
python-jsonpickle-doc - Python library for serializing object graphs into JSON (documentation)
python3-jsonpickle - Python library for serializing object graphs into JSON (Python 3)
```

So you should search for them first, maybe you don't have to do anything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for how to package and deploy your python3 application from the host to another linux machine (let's call it machine1).

First I assume your python application is built correctly with a valid `setup.py` here is the example that I used [see link](https://pythonhosted.org/foo-test/).

1. Installing your python3 application dependencies:

   1.1. Go to your "foo" application directory where the `setup.py` is located and run:

   ```
   $ cd path_to_foo/foo/
   $ python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
   ```

   1.2. It will create a "dist" folder go inside and copy `foo-0.1-py3-none-any.whl` file to machine1

   1.3. Log into machine1 and go to the path of the `whl` file and run:

   ```
   $ cd path_to_whl_file/
   $ pip3 install foo-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
   ```
2. Installing your python3 application package

   2.1. First we need to install fpm (on your host development machine)
   look here for more information [How To Use FPM To Easily Create Packages in Multiple Formats](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fpm-to-easily-create-packages-in-multiple-formats).

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essential
   $ sudo gem install fpm
   ```

   2.2. then go to the directory that holds the foo application and run:

   ```
   $ sudo fpm --python-bin python3 --python-pip pip3 \
     --python-package-name-prefix python3 --no-python-dependencies \
     --python-install-bin /usr/bin -s python -t deb \
     path_to_foo_application/
   ```

   It should create the package `python3-foo_0.1_all.deb`

   2.3.  Log into machine1 and go to the path of the deb package and install it

   ```
   $ cd path_to_deb_package/
   $ sudo dpkg -i python3-foo-_0.1_all.deb
   ```
3. That's it now you can run the application from anywhere (the application is placed at `/usr/bin/`)

Hope that answered your question and helped you with creating/building python3 packages.

**NOTE:** it worked for me on Ubuntu, Debian, and Raspbian.